# Access denied when checking a Shared Data Source

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, tfs

I have the following Shared Data Source Properties in TFS :

Name : MyDW

Type : Microsoft SQL Server

Connecting String :

```
Data Source=aa\\instance;Initial Catalog=MyDW
```

When I try to set User name and Password :

[image]

I get the following error :

> Acess to the the xxxxxxxxxxxx/MyDW.rds id denied

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/create-modify-and-delete-shared-data-sources-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#creating-and-modifying-shared-data-sources) that:

> You must have Manage data sources permissions on the report server to modify the Properties of a Shared Data Sources.

So you first need to check if you have the Manage data sources permission. You need to ask your local administrator to create a role assignment for your account which allows you to access to the shared data source. Users who have access to a shared data source item can change its name, description, connection string, or credential information. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/secure-shared-data-source-items?view=sql-server-ver15).

Or to add you to a group that is already part of a role assignment which has the access.

Check below documents for more information.

[Create and Manage Role Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/create-and-manage-role-assignments?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Role Assignments - Modify or Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/role-assignments-modify-or-delete?view=sql-server-ver15)